# Изменение содержимого текстового поля с использованием Active Accessibility

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, atl

Могу ли я изменить содержимое текстового поля, имея объекты `IAccessible` и `IDispatch`, представляющие это поле в MSAA?

`IAccessible.put_accValue` выдаёт ошибку `HRESULT 80004005`.

Так, конечно, работает, но это как то слишком "хардкорно":

```
pAccChild->accDoDefaultAction(CComVariant((int)CHILDID_SELF));
// SendKeys calls...
```

(default action здесь активирует поле и выделяет его содержимое)